# SUM(DISTINCT) on the same table?

Tags: mysql, sql, math

I currently have table as below:

[image: Accounting Journal Entries]

By executing the code as:

```
SELECT FromLedger, SUM(TransactionVal) 
FROM Journal 
WHERE FromGroup = 'Asset'  
GROUP BY FromLedger
```

I get the result as:
[image]

Simlarly, I get the another set by executing:

```
SELECT ToLedger, SUM(TransactionVal) 
FROM Journal 
WHERE ToGroup = 'Asset'  
GROUP BY ToLedger
```

[image]

I want to get a single table combining the both table with Group By Ledger Id and another column as the difference between the SUM of the above 2 table. In other words, I am looking for table as below

[image]

How do I get it please?

Comment: Its a Journal Entry table and I want to calculate the closing balance for each unique ledger over the period.

Comment: Join the 2 queries on FromLedger = ToLedger and subtract the sums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the 2 queries like this:

```
SELECT t.ToLedger UniqueLedgerId, t.total - f.total ClosingBalance
FROM (SELECT ToLedger, SUM(TransactionVal) total FROM Journal WHERE ToGroup = 'Asset' GROUP BY ToLedger) t
INNER JOIN (SELECT FromLedger, SUM(TransactionVal) total FROM Journal WHERE FromGroup = 'Asset' GROUP BY FromLedger) f
ON f.FromLedger = t.ToLedger
```

or use `UNION ALL` and then aggregate:

```
SELECT t.UniqueLedgerId, SUM(t.TransactionVal) ClosingBalance
FROM (
  SELECT ToLedger UniqueLedgerId, TransactionVal FROM Journal WHERE ToGroup = 'Asset'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT FromLedger, -TransactionVal FROM Journal WHERE FromGroup = 'Asset'
) t
GROUP BY t.UniqueLedgerId
```